# What is the best way to use Twitter Bootstrap in Symfony2?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig

I have used the `Twitter Bootstrap3` to design graphic user interface for many websites. I do love it. Now, I start to learn `Symfony2` for a while. I have skimmed through many tutorials in order to integrate TB with Symfony2. I found two main ways to achieve this:

**With Bundles**

I found two main bundles so far.

1.[MopaBootstrapBundle](https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle)

*PROS*

- New layout structure.
- Many functionality, extra assetic, forms.

*CONS*

- Complex

2.[BcBootstrapBundle](http://knpbundles.com/braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle)

*PROS*

- Simple
- Many functionality, extra assetic, forms.

---

**Without Bundles**

There are two ways to achieve this without using Bundles.

1.[With composer](https://coderwall.com/p/kzyiaw) - it looks very complicated to install. Moreover, I don't know do we can edit less files afterward?

2.[Download directly from TB](http://wwww.getbootstrap.com) - download `jquery`, `bootstrap.js` and `bootstrap.css` files, and simply put them into folders. Then, we can use symlinks to link them.

So, my question is: which method is the best way to integrate Twitter Bootstrap3 with Symfony2? Why?

Answer (score 2):

The other pro of the bundles are that **the form layout is often included**. But there is no good or bad way to do it. Do whatever works for you. I have tried both and still use both.

Answer (score 1):

There is no **best way**. Do whatever you're comfortable with and what suits your project. If you don't plan on overriding any form elements, there's almost no reason to use a separate bundle.